# Speaker Recognition using Deep Learning

Tags: dataset, audio-recognition

I am trying to develop a speaker recognition model using deep learning. I want to use the VoxCeleb2 audio dataset but I cannot find it. The one on their website has YouTube links, but I would rather use data that is already in mp3/audio file format. Any idea where I can get it?

Comment: Probably it is not legal to distribute audio files extracted from Youtube due to copyright issues and therefore you may not find the dataset in such a form.

Comment: Did you locate a copy? I can't even find the youtube links...